# Using integrals only, calculate the area of the greatest rectangle that can be inscribed in an ellipse.

Tags: integration

This question requires the calculation of the area with the use of integration. I know how to do this problem with the concept of maxima and minima . But when I was asked to do it with integration I assumed parametric point in the first quadrant and took the equation of the horizontal length as y=b×sin∅ and calculate the area covered by the rectangle in the first quadrant by integrating to acos∅ and multiplied it by 4.
Then I calculated the area and differentiated it and put dA/d∅ =0 from there i got ∅=π/4 as the point of maxima and finally put the value of ∅ in the equation for max area and got the value of maximum area to be $2ab$ .

Is there any other way to do this question?
Or have I done something wrong?

Comment: I think the question as written would allow for a rectangle whose sides were not "horizontal" and "vertical". "Only" integration is also a bit misleading as you are using (obvious) geometric symmetries, and also implicitly using the convexity of the ellipse. But both these observations may be overcomplicating what is intended.

Answer (score 1):

For an ellipse of axes $2a$ and $2b$, $$\begin{cases}x=a\cos t,\\y=b\sin t\end{cases}$$ and the area of any inscribed rectangle is $$4ab\cos t\sin t=2ab\sin 2t.$$ The maximum is obviously $2ab$.

---

I can't see why/how integrals should be used here, and I can't see how this could be solved with integrals only, as you need to find the extremum.